# How to invoke unexported class' method in go

Tags: go, private

I want to invoke http.Server's newConn method in net/http/server.go

```
func (srv *Server) newConn(rwc net.Conn) *conn {
    c := &conn{
        server: srv,
        rwc:    rwc,
    }
    if debugServerConnections {
        c.rwc = newLoggingConn("server", c.rwc)
    }
    return c
}
```

Tried to access using reflect but errors occured

```
conn := ...
server := &http.Server{}

inputs := make([]reflect.Value, 1)
inputs[0] = reflect.ValueOf(conn)
c := reflect.ValueOf(server).MethodByName("newConn").Call(inputs)
```

```
panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Call on zero Value

goroutine 17 [running, locked to thread]:
reflect.flag.mustBe(0x0, 0x13)
    /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:201 +0xae
reflect.Value.Call(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc420047d10, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc4200e82c0)
    /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:300 +0x38
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: +1 for a question concerning beginners, on availability of methods. don't see a reason to downvote, found myself once in a similar need when debugging code in go.

Comment: This is a nice question, and should not be downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR** You don't. That's the whole point of not exporting things; to prevent direct access to them.

Having said that, this question sounds a lot like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  Perhaps if you can explain what you're trying to accomplish, we can suggest an alternative approach.

**Longer answer**

This can be possible with reflection (as you're attempting). This should only be done in the absolute rarest of situations, if even then.

To help with that, please include a complete, reproducible example. The code you've included doesn't compile, so it's impossible to debug.

Comment: His example is: `reflect.ValueOf(&http.Server{}).MethodByName("newConn").Call([]reflect.Value{})` One line, it compiles. Though you are right, it is unclear what he is trying to accomplish. And he shouldn't be doing this sort of thing anyway.

Comment: I can't post second question in 90 mins. So will be posted concrete question later.

I'm trying to serve http in child process using already accepted socket file descriptor that has been passed by parent process. (Multi process server)

The parent process is a C++ server and accepting inet connection.

The child process is a forked C++ process on start and running go program.

I have succeeded to create net.Conn about passed file descriptor integer.

But I couldn't find proper http serve method using file descriptor (or net.Conn) in go http server.

Comment: @함치헌 `http.Serve` takes a https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Listener , which is an interface that has 3 methods wrapped around a `net.Conn`. If you create a struct that implements this interface using your `net.Conn`, you can pass it to `http.Serve`.

Comment: @함치헌 Don't post a new question. Edit this one.